# How to edit DataGridView Cell in VB.net using a keyboard during runtime?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How can I edit a DataGridView Cell using my mouse and keyboard during runtime? I am using VB.Net 2017. My current settings for the DataGridView  are set to "Enable Editing", but when clicking on a cell or pressing enter nothing happens during runtime

Comment: Delete the data grid view and add a new one. leave the settings the way they are.

Comment: @preciousbetine, your comment is more valuable than the documentation. Could you please convert your comment to an answer?  This solved my issue. I will mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default, a DataGridView's cells are editable during runtime, So in your case, you might have messed up some settings. Delete the Current DataGridView on your Form and add a New one and it should work just fine.